# VisualWorks 7.9.1 Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, smalltalk, file-association, visualworks

I would like to associate ~/vw7.9.1/bin/linux86/vwlinux86gui with .im files on Ubuntu 12.04, so that a double click of an .im file will open it up.

Anyone know the magic?

Thx for any tips...

Comment: it is an old closed question, but in case someone will need it, this is how I made it work on ubunut 16.04 64-bit: create file start.sh,  and add: 
#!/bin/sh

VISUALWORKS=/home/your-folder/vw8.1.1pul

/home/your-folder/vw8.1.1pul/bin/linuxx86_64/visual /home/your folder/vw8.1.1pul/image/visualnc64.im
(using paths listed in userActions.txt)
close the file, add permissions, and run it as ./start.sh

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to make an association. If you make sure that command 'visual' is in your path and is linked to a VM that can run the image, you just need to make sure that the image file's permissions include the executable flag, and you can simply run the image file as any other executable.

Even better setup is to link 'visual' to the shell script in vw7.9.1/preview/bin/VisualWorks.sh and that the collocated VisualWorks.ini file has the proper mapping of the image signature to the corresponding VW installation, and then you can run image files from different VW versions the same way. The script will find the right version of VW to run the image with and also set-up VISUALWORKS environment variable accordingly so that you don't have to set the VW Home by hand. There's a readme next to the script that provides more details.